# jQuery animateNumber - How to prop.animate floats

Tags: jquery, numbers, prop

i try to animate a number. I dont have any problems with ints, but my system doesnt work with floats.

If the propNumberGV would be 5.5 and the new data.value = 10.0, the animations beginns at 0.0 and it doesnt at 5.5. The system works for integers, but not for floats...

```
var propNumberGV = gv == undefined || gv == null || gv == 0.0 ? 0 : gv;
        var dcp = 2;
        var dcf = dcp === 0 ? 1 : Math.pow(10, dcp);
        $("#gameValue").prop('number', propNumberGV).animateNumber({
            number: data.value * dcf,
            numberStep: function(now, tween) {
                var floored_number = Math.floor(now) / dcf,
                target = $("#gameValue");
                if (dcp > 0) {
                  floored_number = floored_number.toFixed(dcp);
                }

                target.text(floored_number);
            }
        }, 4000);
        gv = data.value;
```

I hope you can help me.

jQuery animateNumber: 
https://github.com/aishek/jquery-animateNumber/

Comment: I did it, i just had to give a int instead of a float. (500 instead of 5.00)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem, and I figured it out. The solution was simpler than I thought.

Just multiply your propNumberGV by your dcf when you pass it in. The problem was not that the prop number was starting from 0, it was that the prop number was being divided by your dcf each time (this is how the plugin works), making it appear like it started from 0, when it was actually just some small decimal.

Try this:

```
var propNumberGV = gv == undefined || gv == null || gv == 0.0 ? 0 : gv;
    var dcp = 2;
    var dcf = dcp === 0 ? 1 : Math.pow(10, dcp);
    $("#gameValue").prop('number', (propNumberGV*dcf)).animateNumber({
        number: data.value * dcf,
        numberStep: function(now, tween) {
            var floored_number = Math.floor(now) / dcf,
            target = $("#gameValue");
            if (dcp > 0) {
              floored_number = floored_number.toFixed(dcp);
            }

            target.text(floored_number);
        }
    }, 4000);
    gv = data.value;
```